# ATI Graphics Card Drivees Problem?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I recently obtained an old Dell server from my grandpa. Its old. Has 2.8 GHz Intel Xeon, 155gb HD, ATI rv1000 graphics, and 3gb ddr2 ram. I recent just put Ubuntu 14 on it. It runs very slowly. I've been deDing it coukd be a driver problem for my graphics card. It says my graphics is Gallium 0.4 on lvmpipe. Anyone know what I should do? Im Fairly new to Linux so bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get Ubuntu working properly with my Video Card, but I installed Lubuntu on my system instead and that improved performance a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using the open graphics driver. Please try the proprietary one to see if it suits better your card.

## Installing AMD-ATI proprietary driver

1. Open a terminal using your keyboard: `Ctrl + Alt + T`
2. Enter the following command: `sudo apt-get install fglrx`
3. Reboot your computer

Comment: I will try that. I read somewhere that that could screw up your graphics for the rv1000?

Comment: You're right. Your graphics model (RV100 / Radeon 7000) is unfortunately not supported anymore by the proprietary driver ([source](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware#Radeon_Legacy_.28Open_Source.29)).

Comment: Could you try this command in a terminal and report here the output: `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices; sudo ubuntu-drivers list`

Comment: I will do that. I tried the fgkrx install just in case I misunderstood, so when I can get rid of that I will try that command.

Comment: I'm trying to run the command now; it doesn't seem to do anything. It asks for root password, I type it in, then nothing. Just sits there.

Comment: Picture of my terminal:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByD7d3tXa1-qTTh4NkFwWnYwdjg/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: I also ran the command "lshw" and got:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByD7d3tXa1-qaDRaUjRTemxydlk/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Open source drivers are your only option. You should give a try with Lubuntu 14.04+ or Ubuntu 12.04 to see if your system is responsive enough.

Comment: OK, I also tried with Linux Mint, and that was even worse. So are there no open source drivers for my specific card?